# .NET, JSON, Embedded, Free Commercial-Use data management solution? What to do?

Tags: c#, database, json, nosql, licensing

I am trying to develop a data management solution for a commercial product that meets several criteria. The criteria and my reasoning are as follows:

1. The solution should be in C# or support C#
2. Manage data as JSON
3. No external schema maintenance
4. Be able to cache some or all data in memory and persist to disk
5. Not require an additional installation
6. If the solution involves third-party software, the license must support no-cost commercial use

**Requirement #1**: My application is written in C# and I would prefer that any solution does not involve integrating with applications, libraries, or code in another language.

**Requirement #2**: There are several JSON-based tools and libraries that I would like to utilize, so I need a solution where data is either in or easily converts to/from JSON.

**Requirement #3**: I want to avoid the schema maintenance that comes with using relational database solutions. I prefer to manage mismatched data-to-object mappings in code and have code update older data instead of managing schema updates separately.

**Requirement #4**: I require some or all data to be loaded into memory at all times, and all data to be persisted to disk. Whether data persists in memory or not should be optional per data type.

**Requirement #5**: When installing my product I don't want to have any secondary installations or have any external services running other than my application. A completely self-contained solution is best.

**Requirement #6**: The intended use is for a distributed commercial product. I would prefer to avoid any additional fees or licensing issues that come with many third-party solutions.

To date I have tried several solutions. Originally I did not have as many constraints and went with a [SQLite.NET](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) and its use wasn't unpleasant, but the overhead from schema maintenance and data format was more than I would like. I investigated a lot of NoSQL solutions (such as [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/)), other third-party solutions (Karvonite), and simple JSON file storage implementations, but I'm not satisfied with any of them.

Is there a custom approach or solution that I am missing, that someone else has used successfully? I'm hoping that I am simply overlooking the option(s) that I am after, and that some NoSQL and .NET experts out there have enough experience in this area to point me in the right direction.

**EDIT**: In case any original commentators are confused, I updated the question and title to better adhere to SO's policies.

Comment: I seem to remember that MongoDB only requires you to launch a executable as a server without an installation. Would it be a option to bundle those binaries with your software? I'm using Mongo as an example, mind. Don't even know if that would meet your requirements.

Comment: Not yet; out of the current suggestions, RavenDB comes the closest aside from the licensing though.

Comment: @Descalon can you provide resources that elaborate on integrating with MongoDB in such a way as to meet all four criteria listed in the OP? I didn't see these kinds of options in my own research, but I could have easily missed something.

Comment: @jmblack Alas, but I can't. While doing some research I stumbled across the fact that MongoDB is AGPL licensed, therefore it won't meet criteria 4 in the OP.

Comment: The question was incorrectly closed. It should have been closed because it's asking for tool/library recommendations. I find the question very interesting as I'm also seeking for the same. But it's still not allowed here at SO.

Comment: @jgauffin I reworded the question to match the recommendation from the accepted answer in this thread as best I could, so that it is a 'solve a problem' question instead of 'give me a library' which is limiting: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question

Comment: @jmblack did you find the library of choice? I voted to re-open the question, but need another 2 votes.

Comment: @trailmax Thanks. The most promising answer I previously received was for Biggy (https://github.com/robconery/biggy) but I have not used it yet.

Comment: @jmblack I was just looking on it yesterday. From my understanding this is based on top of relational db, which I was hoping to avoid. RavenDb embedded sounds ideal, but it is not free.

Comment: @trailmax Either that project or a spin-off project is supposed to be implementing the memory/file JSON component without any RDBMS attached.

Answer (score 1):

Fluent NHibernate Automapping on top of SQLite would meet all your requirements except  **edit** #2 - "NoSQL, preferably all data is a JSON document"

It automaps a relational DB schema from your object model...does not use JSON. **edit** You might be able to save JSON data as BLOB, however. (caveat: I know almost nothing about JSON)

Comment: Thanks Tom, but #3 is an important requirement to me since I would like the database to be invisible to an end user. I've used SQLite for a lightweight DB solution before. I like it for certain uses, but I asked this question specifically looking for a tool to meet needs that SQLite does not.

Comment: Having the database naturally work with JSON documents is also quite important, which is the other reason SQLite doesn't meet my needs or the criteria I listed in the OP.

Comment: Oops! I meant item #2 - see correction. For a commercial application, it sounds like RavenDB might be your best choice...but you would have to pay licensing.

Comment: Ahh that makes more sense. I agree, RavenDB seems to be the most promising solution technically. Maybe a new project will come along that meets all four criteria and someone will post about it here. One can hope.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the [Karvonite Framework](http://www.karvonite.com/)? The Karvonite Framework provides a strongly-typed embedded database system that includes a portable library implementation for .NET / Windows Store / Silverlight / Windows Phone / Xbox development. I have only used this for small database implementations but so far it has met every one of my needs.

Comment: I've been wanting to look into this option more since I had not heard of Karvonite before. Though at first glance Karvonite is not going to meet criteria #2, so it's not a perfect solution for this question. Interesting suggestion that I want to experiment with though, so thanks!